# Cakephp and Jasper reports integration

Tags: cakephp, jasper-reports

Does anyone have any direct experience in integrating Cakephp and Jasper Reports?

I'm considering using Cakephp as a framework for a large project that will require the development of 75 - 100 complex reports. Ideally I would like to generate all of these reports from within the Cakephp code (not running a stand alone Jasper UI). I'm expecting that all of the generated reports will be in a PDF format.

Thank you for sharing your thoughts,

Dale

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the JasperReports ReST API and their PHP Client.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/php-client

Note that you will still need to design and test the reports with Jasper tools, what the above will give you however is the ability to call the report with certain parameters from Cake.

Regards,

-Rami

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have a Experience in Integrating jasper Report to PhP.

Tomcat need to be installed on your system with java Bridge.
very Easy to Done in Windows and difficult for me in Linux still i configured that too.
I faced the problem Java Vitual Size -xms like something .
1. As you configured the Java Bridge 
Download java Bridge war below link
http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/download.php

2. create a Report Folder
3. Find Java File http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc
   Paste to Report Folder
4. create a jasper report For Testing With or Withour parameter as you want
5. Cakephp Working code to genrate pdf

create Report_test.php and paste the below code and change the data according to your database configuration